# Create a copy of the folder within same remote server with SFTP

Tags: scala, sftp, jsch

I am using JSch API to connect to remote server through SFTP. I need to get a copy of a folder which is exist in the remote server into the same server. Is there any method implemented to do this kind of things in JSch? Or be kind to give me an advice to do the above use-case. (I am working in Scala).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can not use "sftp" channel to do this task ans we have to use "exec" channel to do this task. Using "exec" channel we can execute Linux commands as follows,

```
val command = "mkdir testDir"
val channelExec: ChannelExec = session.openChannel("exec").asInstanceOf[ChannelExec]
channelExec.setCommand(command);
channelExec.connect
```

Go through the following links to get more details

> http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec
>
> http://www.journaldev.com/246/java-program-to-run-shell-commands-on-ssh-enabled-system
>
> http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html

Thank you for all participants

Answer (score 2):

Support for copying files remotely is rare in SFTP servers. There's `copy-file` extension to SFTP, but few servers/clients do support it.
See [draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-extensions-00](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-extensions-00).

In the most widespread OpenSSH SFTP server it is supported only by very recent [version 9.0](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0). And JSch does not support it at all.

Alternatives:

- Download the folder and reupload it to a new location (pure SFTP solution)
- Use `cp` command in a "exec" channel (not SFTP anymore, requires shell access)